# Brochure: Holiday Cruises

Tags: reading-comprehension

> ## Holiday Cruises
>
> Travel in style on our popular Caribbean Cruise.
>
> - Ten nights
> - Choose from three departure dates: March 4, March 23, April 5
> - The cruise departs from Fort Lauderdale, Florida
> - Ports of call in Mexico, Belize, and the Cayman Islands

**TASK** These inferences are based on the above brochure. Place a check mark (✓) next to each correct inference and underline the information in the brochure that supports the statement.

2. The company offers several cruise dates in the summer.

Is the line "Choose from three departure dates: March 4, March 23, April 5", an indication of the cruise dates? The answer key didn't mark this statement, so could you guys please tell me the reason why? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would be an incorrect inference.  While those are the dates of the cruises,  "in the summer" means in June, July an August in most places in the Northern Hemisphere.  The dates given there are all in **Spring** (or late winter depending on when you think the first day of spring is).

Comment: Nobody agrees on when the first day of spring is.  https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/our-very-unscientific-poll-on-when-each-season-starts/  Whatever you say, you will disagree with most people.